# I have an error when running my code: 'y_test' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, prediction

I am running this code to train and predict the data:

```
#Create the testing data set
#Create a new array containing scaled values from index 1543 to 2003
test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 60: , :]
#Create the data sets x_test and y_test
x_test= []
Y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
  x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])

#Convert the data to a numpy array
x_test = np.asarray(x_test)

#reshape the data
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

#Get the models predicted price values
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

When I run the following code for the RMSE

```
#Get the root mean squared error (RMSE)
rmse=np.sqrt(np.mean(((predictions- y_test)**2)))
rmse
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-555ecc401e59> in <module>()
      1 #Get the root mean squared error (RMSE)
----> 2 rmse=np.sqrt(np.mean(((predictions- y_test)**2)))
      3 rmse

NameError: name 'y_test' is not defined
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized `Y_test` but you are using `y_test` to calculate `rmse`, please make sure you take care of alphabet cases.